# Return Type of a function giving out timestamp using Boost

Tags: c++, boost

What should be the return type of the function and the variable in the below example using boost library?

```
? func (void);
{
   boost::posix_time::ptime time_stamp;
   time_stamp = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time; 
   return time_stamp;
}

int main()
{

   ? Var;
   Var = func();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `auto`? And `auto Var = func()`?

Comment: Why would the answer be anything else than `boost::posix_time::ptime` that is already written ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `boost::posix_time::ptime`. Your original code has an error, `universal_time` is a function that you need to call. I changed it in the (untested) code below.

```
boost::posix_time::ptime func()
{
   boost::posix_time::ptime time_stamp = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time(); 
   return time_stamp;
}

int main()
{    
   boost::posix_time::ptime Var = func();
   return 0;
}
```

Also, if you are using C++11, you except for the function signature of `func`, you can replace `boost::posix_time::ptime` with `auto`.

```
boost::posix_time::ptime func()
{
   return boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time(); 
}

int main()
{    
   auto Var = func();
}
```

(For convenience, I like to nickname the `boost::posix_time` namespace using `namespace pt = boost::posix_time`; this way it shortens to `pt::ptime`.)

For a good overview of boost date/time functionality, see [Chapter 36. Boost.DateTime](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.datetime).